# Map ACPI events to X keys (or to custom commands)

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xmodmap, acpi

Some of the multimedia keys on my Lenovo X1 Carbon aren't recognized by `xev`. Each time I press the "volume down" key, for example, I get an output that looks like:

```
FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

However, the "key pressing event" is recognized by ACPI. Using `acpi_listen` gives me an output of:

```
button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K
button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K
```

How can I map this to the more classic `XF86AudioLowerVolume` and other similar keys? If that's impossible, what's the best way to directly map this to a custom script?

Comment: The focus events mean that some application, possibly your window manager, is stealing those events (and acting on them), probably because it has bound actions to it. So they *are* already recognized, and processed.

Comment: OK, thanks! I'm using i3 as a window manager. There isn't anything visible (or audible) happening when I press those keys, so I don't know what that could be. Is it possible to know what's stealing the ACPI events?

Comment: Additional info: using `wmctrl -l` in addition to `xev`, I can see that the window `0x4800001` above is the "N/A Event Tester" window from xev. So this doesn't provide any useful info as to what is stealing the event =(

Comment: Many desktop environments are setup by default to react on those events, but there's so many variations I have no idea what it is in your case. Googling about volume control keys for i3/Gnome/whatever you use might turn up something. `xlsclients` might also show more possible culprits, for example, I can see `ibus` on my system with `xlsclients`, but not with `wmctrl -l`.

Comment: i3 is not supposed to do any of that, it's a minimalistic window manager. The recommended way to do volume control is through bindings like `bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume`. I looked at the output of `xlsclients`, and there is nothing there susceptible to steal ACPI events (some shells, and some programs that I all closed to verify that the problem was still there).

Comment: Look if you can remove any configuration files for acpi events in ` /etc/acpi/events/`